# How can I mock a class that has a static field in my example?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

It's been two days that I am trying to solve this!
Here is the thing: I have a Class as below:

```
public class TaskEntity extends Index {

    public String title;
    public String description;
    public UUID posterId;
    public Long time;
    public String address;
    public GeoPoint location;

    public static Finder find = new Finder(TaskEntity.class);

    //some methods
}
```

which extends this abstract class:

```
public abstract class Index implements Indexable {
    //some public non static fields
    // some methods

    public static class Finder {
        private final Class type;
        private IndexQueryPath queryPath;

        public Finder(Class type) {
            this.type = type;
            T t = IndexUtils.getInstanceIndex(type); // error here!
            this.queryPath = t.getIndexPath();
        }

        public IndexQueryPath getIndexPath() {

            IndexType indexTypeAnnotation = this.getClass().getAnnotation(IndexType.class);
            if(indexTypeAnnotation == null) {
                Logger.error("ElasticSearch : Class " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " no contain @IndexType(name) annotation ");
            }
            String indexType = indexTypeAnnotation.name();

            String indexName = IndexService.INDEX_DEFAULT; // This is not defined, therefore throw a NullPointerException
            IndexName indexNameAnnotation = this.getClass().getAnnotation(IndexName.class);
            if(indexNameAnnotation != null) {
                indexName = indexNameAnnotation.name();
            }

               return new IndexQueryPath(indexName, indexType);
         }

        // some methods
    }

}
```

Simply I try to mock the TaskEntity class without any extra code as below:

```
public class TaskManagementServiceImplTest {
    @Mock
    private TaskEntity taskEntity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void emptyTest(){

    }
}
```

BOOM:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.Index.getIndexPath(Index.java:41)
    at com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.Index$Finder.(Index.java:164)
    at models.elasticsearch.TaskEntity.(TaskEntity.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor6.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:45)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:128)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:63)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:111)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:60)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:143)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.standardInject(AnnotationEnabler.java:84)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:51)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:90)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:292)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:104)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.IndexService.(IndexService.java:45)
    ... 36 more
```

I am mocking my TaskEntity class to avoid initializing my search engine. However, as I can see even when I want to mock it it tries to access stuff that it shouldn't. Is there a way to avoid this? Is there a way to mock TaskEntity and somehow ignoring that "find" field?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just to make sure I got the question right, you want to mock `TaskEntity` at the highest level?  You don't want the code going into this `Finder` constructor?  You want to mock a `TaskEntity` and manipulate the `Finder` inside of it, without it firing off using the normal coded functionality?

Comment: Yes, I don't want the code going into this Finder constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easy solution is to mock the `IndexUtils.getInstanceIndex(type)` call.  That looks like a static call which is setting that `t` variable, which is then trying to be used in the next line `t.getIndexPath();`.  When mocking the static `IndexUtils`, make sure to include in your `@PrepareForTest` annotation at least `IndexUtils` and `Finder`.  This would need to be handled in your `setUp()` but before you try and `initMocks(this)`.  That way, when the execution gets to the error line (upon initialization of the `TaskEntity` mock) it will have the hooks to return the proper mocked values to continue with the setup.

If you want the code to not go into the `Finder` constructor at all, it could take a few more hoops to jump through.  Your setup would have to change a bit to handle the static.  Make sure to still include `Finder` as well as `TaskEntity` in your `@PrepareTest` annotation.

```
@Mock
private TaskEntity taskEntity;
@Mock
private Finder findMock;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(Finder.class);
  PowerMockito.whenNew(Finder.class).withArguments(TaskEntity.class).thenReturn(findMock);
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void emptyTest(){

}
```

This above code is a little tricky and I am not sure if it will work for you.  I am having trouble creating some shell classes locally to do testing with.  I tried simplifying the ones you provided but I am still trying to grasp the setup and correlation between all the complex objects you have.  If there are any errors with this, let me know and I can try and debug through them.